# how to get an .snk file from VB (2008) project

Tags: vb.net

i have a VB project but i don't know how to get a .snk file in order to generate a SN key, any help.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from the project properties menu.

Go to Project ->  Properties -> Choose the 'signing' tab on the left.

Sleect the 'Sign the assembly' checkbox. You will get the option to create a new .snk key file in the dropdown.

Comment: i try to sign the assembly using <NEW..> and type in my password then i got a .pfx file but not .snk file, why?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this from a Visual Studio Tools command line, using the strong name tool.

sn -k keyPair.snk

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23(VS.80).aspx

Comment: if i use VS tools in command line i'm able to produce the .snk file. thanks.